# Run .exe by MATLAB - License error

Tags: matlab, licensing, exe

I need to Run a .exe in a MATLAB project which changes some parameters in a txt file. I wrote:

```
system('C:\path\to\Program1.exe')
```

but it doesn't work and the error shown is:

> Program1 ERROR: License not detected!

The program is correctly installed with license and it works, if I open the application. The license txt file is in the same folder as the .exe file.
What is the problem? Is the source code necessary?

Comment: The program is not correctly installed or there wouldnt be license error!

Comment: Thanks! But the program works (it's for that reason that I wrote that is correctly installed): I put the license when I installed it (the program owner gave me one license generated for my pc) and, using it without Matlab, it always worked. So, what you suggest to do?

Comment: Maybe try `cd('C:\path\to\')` first. It's a problem with `Program1`, not with MATLAB and as we don't know that program it is very difficult to help here.

Comment: You need to investigate how your program works in **batch mode** or **command line**. (because nothing else is Matlab doing. It opens internally the windows cmd and executes your command) There you will the instructions on how to include the license from command line

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It's true: I tried to run it from command prompt the error is exactly the one shown by Matlab. How it is possible to find the instruction to include the license? What I need to do?
Since maybe you need some details for help me, the program is TOPKAPI-X 1.2.1 and the developers gave me a license generated for my product code